# Восклицание внутри предложения

Tags: пунктуация, вставная-конструкция

Возможно ли ставить восклицание/вопрос/подобное в предложении без окончания оного?
Например:

```
У Доктора два(!|,) два сердца!
```

Возможно ли тут оставить восклицательный знак без ущерба остальному тексту или надо ограничиться запятой?
И если это разрешено, то по какому правилу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> И если это разрешено, то по какому правилу?

[См.:](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103)

> **§ 6.** Вопросительный и восклицательный знаки ставятся внутри предложения, если они относятся к вставным конструкциям **или сами
>   замещают вставки**, передавая соответствующее отношение пишущего к
>   содержанию: *Девчушка (как же ее звали?) шла по улице, как по своей
>   жизни* (Мак.); *— Да, — продолжал ученый, — наш мозг не готов к
>   восприятию этой идеи, как и многих других, до которых (парадоксально!)
>   он сам же додумался* (Сол.); ***На остальных досках шахматисты
>   одержали восемь (!) побед*** (журн.).

Comment: Отлично, спасибо. А обязательно ли помещать эти знаки в скобки?

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, подойдет такой вариант:

У Доктора два (двА!) сердца! Здесь основное восклицание приходится на второе числительное.

Сравнить: У Доктора два(!),  два сердца!  Не очень ясная интонация.

Comment: Ваш вариант (двА) уж вообще против всех и всяческих правил.

Comment: ДвА - это у меня ударение так обозначено (на букве А), а какие еще правила нарушены?

Comment: Где восклицание происходит - это другой, хотя и интересный вопрос. Это пример. Скобки вокруг этой... частицы... знака обязательны?

Comment: Больше никакие не нарушены. )

Comment: Чтобы выбрать подходящую форму, для образца возьмем пример из правила: На остальных досках шахматисты одержали восемь побед! Восклицание относится ко всему предложению, а мы хотели бы выделить количество. Как это сделать? Можно просто повторить цифру: На остальных досках шахматисты одержали восемь, восемь побед! Можно поставить (!), как в примере: На остальных досках шахматисты одержали восемь (!) побед. Можно попробовать совместить варианты для усиления эффекта: На остальных досках шахматисты одержали  восемь (восемь!) побед.  Все три варианта подходят для вашего примера.

Comment: К сожалению, я не совсем поняла, какое оформление вам предложили в ответе, так как предложение полностью не обозначено.